# GCM push message encoding

Tags: android, encoding, push

I am trying to send push notifications using following code:

```
    Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("appName", appData.name)
.addData("message", pushData.message).build();
```

On the receiving side my code is:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

When the message is in English, latin charset, everything works. However, when I try other languages or the character ç, they arrive as question marks or are deleted from the string.

Note: it's encoded in utf-8

Comment: I have pretty much the same code `intent.getExtras().getString("message");` but it works, so it makes me wonder if it is not the message that is coming already broken. You may need to check the encode you are using to send.

Comment: The incoming message is indeed already broken, I see it on the Intent object. The message doesn't contain certain characters (e.g. ç). But the pushData.message looks ok: using the debugger I see the character is there... is there a way to state the encoding to use?

Comment: what server are you using to send the push notifications.

Comment: Apache Tomcat 6.0, do you think a change in the server.xml might help?

Comment: I dont think the server has anything to do with it. It is usually a configuration from the application running on the server. That is what i meant by what server you are using.

Comment: Having the same issue how did you resolve this?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I looked in the android source and I  see com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Message, List<String>) That method does the following HttpURLConnection conn =
        post(GCM_SEND_ENDPOINT, "application/json", requestBody). It appears they are not specifying "application/json; charset=utf-8" which means the default platform charset will kick in. Isn't this is a BIG problem?

Comment: Digging even deeper I find com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(String, String, String) does byte[] bytes = body.getBytes(). Why do they use platform charset?

Comment: @Yepher please see my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break with the debugger and view the bytes of the message you think you're sending

Comment: Funny, how didn't I think of that! It simply showed me that I have the wrong data...

Answer (score 9):

Java server

```
Message messagePush = new Message.Builder().addData("message", URLEncoder.encode("your message éèçà", "UTF-8")))
```

Android application

```
String message = URLDecoder.decode(intent.getStringExtra("message"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: this doesnt work for topic messages though. only general gcm messages. Do you have a similar solution for topics?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. Non ASCII characters where corrupted when received on the Android client. I personally believe this is a problem within the Google GCM server library implementation.

In the Android GCM library I see the method:

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Message, List<String>)
```

That method does the following

```
HttpURLConnection conn = post(GCM_SEND_ENDPOINT, "application/json", requestBody)
```

They should atleast specify "application/json; **charset=utf-8**" or whatever encoding they used or better yet force it to UTF-8. *Isn't this is a BIG problem?*

Digging even deeper I find the method:

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(String, String, String)
```

which does:

```
byte[] bytes = body.getBytes()
```

Why do they use the platform default charset? Especially since it is not likely to align with the devices default charset.

**Work Around**

Pass the following property as an argument to the JVM "***-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8***" This instructs Java to use UTF-8 as the platform default charset when doing things like "blah".getBytes(). This is bad practice but what can you do when it is someone else's library?

Comment: They updated gcm-server library and, it is the same as what you recommended. However, it still is not working for me and I keep getting broken messages. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the gcm-server library. My workaround was using a custom sender to override the `post` method and use UTF8 as encoding in the `getBytes()` call.
It works on Google App Engine.

The code of the custom sender class:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

/**
 * Workaround to avoid issue #13 of gcm-server
 * @see https://code.google.com/p/gcm/issues/detail?id=13&q=encoding
 * 
 * @author rbarriuso /at/ tribalyte.com
 *
 */
public class Utf8Sender extends Sender {

    private final String key;

    public Utf8Sender(String key) {
        super(key);
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection post(String url, String contentType, String body) throws IOException {
        if (url == null || body == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("arguments cannot be null");
        }
        if (!url.startsWith("https://")) {
            logger.warning("URL does not use https: " + url);
        }
        logger.fine("Utf8Sender Sending POST to " + url);
        logger.finest("POST body: " + body);
        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes(UTF8);
        HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection(url);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + key);
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        try {
            out.write(bytes);
        } finally {
            close(out);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    private static void close(Closeable closeable) {
        if (closeable != null) {
            try {
                closeable.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ignore error
                logger.log(Level.FINEST, "IOException closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

These were some good solutions, however they didnt help me because I was using topic messaging to send notifications. As per [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)

> The HTTP header must contain the following headers:
>   Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY 
>   Content-Type: application/json for
>   JSON; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 for plain text.
>   If Content-Type is omitted, the format is assumed to be plain text.

However, because I am using cloud endpoints and my app (already out in the wild) is expecting json, formatting the request in plain text wasnt viable. The solution was to ignore the document above, and in my backend, format the http request header as such:

```
 connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

Like magic, suddenly all special characters (read: Japanese) is going through to my application with no front end changes being made. My complete http post code is below`( where payload = Cloud endpoint model object, converted to json<String> via Gson):`

```
 try {
        URL url = new URL("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        byte[] bytes=payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        try {
            out.write(bytes);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // OK
            log.warning("OK");
        } else {
            // Server returned HTTP error code.
            log.warning("some error "+connection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Japes. out.write(payload.getBytes("UTF-8")); is working for me, even if setting "Content-Type" as "application/json".